# Linux API Calls to implement rm, mv, and cp

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, gnu-coreutils

I'm writing my own little shell in C, or at least I'm going to start today.  I want to implement three functions.

- `remove file1`

What system calls would I need for this? Just open file and delete its contents or is there a system call to delete a file besides using `rm`?

- `mycopy source destination`

For this I was thinking of having a buffer and open file1 read into buffer and write out to file2 but I don't know how to actually put this into code if anyone can throw together a little example that would help a bunch.

- `move source destination`

Would this just implement copy and remove?

My main problem is using the argv[] parameters I've never done that so its new to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to see what system calls the linux coreutils use.  The system calls have `man` pages as well, which you can look up (e.g. `man unlink`).

For example...

```
jason@io /tmp $ strace rm foo
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "foo"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x20dd000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2a46c76000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=135313, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 135313, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2a46c54000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\370\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1677176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3784472, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2a466ba000
mprotect(0x7f2a4684d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f2a46a4c000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x192000) = 0x7f2a46a4c000
mmap(0x7f2a46a52000, 16152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2a46a52000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2a46c53000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2a46c52000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2a46c51000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2a46c52700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2a46a4c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f2a46c77000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f2a46c54000, 135313)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x20dd000
brk(0x20fe000)                          = 0x20fe000
open("/usr/lib64/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1607712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1607712, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2a46ac8000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", W_OK)        = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", 0)            = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Oh dude you're awesome

Answer (score 4):

> I'm writing my own little shell in C, or at least I'm going to start today.

If you're writing a *shell*, you don't need to implement these functions; they already exist as the coreutils executables `rm`, `cp`, and `mv`. These are not typically part of a shell, and don't need to be.

Regardless!

> ./remove file1 What system calls would I need for this? Just open file and delete its contents or is there a system call to delete a file besides using rm?

[`unlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink).

> ./mycopy source destination For this I was thinking of having a buffer and open file1 read into buffer and write out to file2 but I don't know how to actually put this into code if anyone can throw together a little example that would help a bunch.

Correct. There's no "single-step" call for this; just [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) (twice), [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), and [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

> And then ./move would just implement copy and remove pretty much right ?

No! That'd be really slow for large files, and wouldn't work at all for directories. The system call you want is [`rename()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename).

(However, note that `rename()` doesn't work across file systems. In that case, you do need to copy and remove files… possibly even recursively, if you're moving a directory.)

Comment: Awesome thanks for telling me which system calls I needed that helps tremendously.  I've got the remove and move working but mycopy isn't working. Could anyone post even a 3 liner c code example on how to read from a file into a buffer (not large enough to hold the entire file, say int buf[128]).  I want to be able to play with the buffer size to see how it affects speed that's why I don't want it to large. But anyways I can't figure out how to copy a file.

Comment: I'm trying to make the function mycopy(./pathname/textfile.txt) so that the path to the file can be supplied when called.  But read and write don't seem to take a variable as the path name. Or at least it's not working for me. I'll post the code when I get home.